# SOLID - обсуждение Open Closed Principle

Tags: php, solid

> Бертран Мейер в основном известен как основоположник термина Принцип открытости/закрытости, который появился в 1988 году в его книге Object-Oriented Software Construction. Идея была в том, что однажды разработанная реализация класса в дальнейшем требует только исправления ошибок, а новые или изменённые функции требуют создания нового класса. Этот новый класс может переиспользовать код исходного класса через механизм наследования. Производный подкласс может реализовывать или не реализовывать интерфейс исходного класса.

То есть получается если мы создаем например класс `Человек`, который имеет методы скажем `поесть`, `поспать`, `попить`. Потом скажем через время нам нужно создать класс `Работник` с методами - `работать`, `получать зарплату` и скажем ему нужен еще метод `общаться`, то что получается мы не можем человеку добавить этот метод `общаться`, так как это нарушит принципы SOLID? А только можем добавить его в класс `Работник` или любой другой который наследуется `Человека`?...

Но это ведь некорректно?... Мы можем попросту что-то забыть добавить в базовый класс, но после уже нельзя модифицировать его, а только дополнять и переопределять базовый класс?

Этот принцип же породит множество ненужных классов, наследующих базовый.

Из википедии:

> Solid - принципы, когда применяются вместе, предназначены для повышения вероятности того, что программист создаст систему, которую будет легко поддерживать и расширять в течение долгого времени[3]. Принципы SOLID - это руководства, которые могут применяться во время работы над программным обеспечением для удаления запахов кода предписывая программисту выполнять рефакторинг исходного кода, пока тот не станет разборчиво написанным и расширяемым. Это часть общей стратегии гибкой и адаптивной разработки

Но данный принцип противоречит концепции (разборчиво написанного кода и расширяемости). Т.е если у нас уже есть множество созданных объектов 'Человек', и в проекте мы хотим чтобы они теперь могли общаться, после добавления данного метода в другой класс, мы должны все наши объекты создать на базе другого класса.

Т.е по логике, по концепции , по здравому смыслу (чтобы не переписывать код)..дополнение должно быть произведено именно в классе 'человек'. + мы получаем возможность создавать людей как имеющих общаться так и не умеющих - но это является ошибкой проектирования кода проекта .

Comment: Вероятно надо создать класс `Человек общительный` с методом `Общаться`, который будет потомком класса `Человек`  и уже от него отнаследовать `Работника`.

Comment: скажем за год использования данного класса человека нам еще может понадобится по 1-2 методу за раз...и так скажем 30 раз..это что 50-60 классов создавать?.....разве не логично что если человек имеет метод общаться....то этот метод должен быть внесен именно в класс "человек"...а не создавать класс "общительный человек" - темболее прилагательные - это всегда методы или свойства объекта, глаголы это всегда методы а существительные - это либо свойства объекта либо имя объекта....

Comment: Если у вас в проекте уже есть `Человек`, и вы хотите посередине проекта добавить ему возможность `общаться`, возможно, это ошибка начального проектирования.

Answer (score 4):

SOLID - это не догмы, а рекомендации. Обычно, если им следовать, то код получается легче дорабатывать и тестировать. Но это может приводить к тому, что кода может быть больше. Чем больше программируешь, тем больше понимаешь как лучше найти баланс.

Кроме наследования есть другие инструменты - например, инкапсуляция, интерфейсы. Я бы сделал `ОбщительныйИнтерфейс` пока из одного метода `общаться`. И нужные наследники `Человека` реализовывали бы этот интерфейс. Также, если многие потомки `Человека` `общаются` схожим образом, то, чтобы не дублировать код, вынес бы логику `общения` в отдельный класс и инкапсулировал его в нужных `Человеков`.

Comment: А какая разница догма это или рекоммедация (в википедии написано принципы), если она несет вред проектированию системы, а не пользу?....Т.е вы хотите сказать что дорабатывать и тестировать 50 классов созданных на базе базового в следствии закрытия к изменению базового класса - проще?......Ок предположим есть у нас класс человек реализующий различные интерфейсы  и мы вводим новый интерфейс "ОбщительныйИнтерфейс"  и задаем что человек теперь реализует и этот интерфейс, но это опять нарушение данного принципа.

Comment: Некоторые программисты считают, что бывает всего три вида чисел - 0, 1 и бесконечность. В реальности у вас будет редко более 5 наследников. Если у вас получается 50 наследников и они действительно нужны (а нельзя обойтись каким-то свойством объекта), то у вас очень сложная система и её делает несколько человек. Когда код в разных классах - это хорошо, потому что они могут дорабатывать не мешая друг другу и когда один поменяет свой класс, с меньшей вероятностью поломает код других.

Comment: В реальности вероятность того что мы создали какойто класс например "Человек" и не создали все ему необходимые методы (например плавать, пойти из точки в точку Б, спать, сидеть, бежать и т.д) - оч большая, следственно - вероятность того что мы N раз (например теже 50) будем дополнять данный класс новыми методами - не такая и низкая....(и получиться не 5 наследников а столько сколько раз мы забудем реализовать какойто метод)...

Comment: Да согласен когда код в разных классах это хорошо, но только в том случае если это нужно......ведь это разная реализация (реализуя другой класс)...вы никак не влияете на код, который уже написан и использует базовый класс......а что собственно можно поламать введя в базовый класс новый метод...который еще нигде не используется?

Comment: Вводите новый public метод в базовый класс - надо думать как он работает во всех наследниках и может даже писать на него тесты в наследниках, потому что могут быть нюансы. То есть можно делать, но это сложнее, чем добавить новый класс. А много классов администрировать тоже сложнее. В любом случае плохо, нужно выбирать из двух зол. Но, в любом случае, лучше не делать классы с 50 public методами :) “Rule of 30” in Refactoring in Large Software Projects - https://dzone.com/articles/rule-30-%E2%80%93-when-method-class-or

Comment: Помоему мы немного усложняем ))) И разговор в другое русло перетек ))  Ну метод можно переопределить в наследнике если это нужно......да и вообще не о наследниках речь ))).....я просто о том что видя класс человек - я хочу видеть все его методы.....а не рыться в поисках метода "идти из точки А в точку Б ", в классах "Человек", "Работник", "ЧеловекУмеющийХодить"....ведь потом окажется что и Рабоник тоже умеет ходить тогда согласно принципу Open Closed нужно создавать класс "Работник Умеющий Ходить"....вообщем это какойто абсурд = )))

Comment: В простых системах будет мало и преимуществ, и недостатков от SOLID - даже, если на каждый чих делать класс, всё равно их будет мало; но и если засунуть все методы в один класс, тоже особого вреда не будет, если вся система состоит из десятка классов даже по 50 методов. В сложных системах от SOLID будет больше пользы, но и недостатков тоже больше. Но без применения принципов SOLID всё ещё хуже.

Comment: @LesyukAlexey в ответ на  вопрос что же может поломать нарушение данного принципа. Представьте целевую аудиторию вашего проекта не как конечного пользователя а как разработчиков чего либо более крупного. Вы не знаете что будут делать с вашей к примеру библиотекой куда будут подключать ваши сущности и каким образом это будет происходить. Возможно к примеру будет использоваться та же работа с метаданными класса. И не учтены метод вдруг появившийся в классе добавит хлопот. Но это все лирика. Всевозможные принципы это правила понятные всей команде работающей до и после вас над проектом.

Comment: Ну мы тут обсуждаем не все принципы SOLID а только один,  да если один класс имеет 200 методов ничего хорошого тут нет, но и когда у нас 50 классов с 4 методами вместо этого тоже ничего хорошоего в этом нет. Если класс разрастается до N методов можно делать его абстрактным (что не позволит создать человека который не умеет общаться), на базе него создать класс который наследуется от данного абстрактного что даст нам возможность использовать все методы человека, а также позволит не держать в одном классе много методов, если в таком ракурсе еще применять принцип OPEN CLOSED тогда он имеет смысл

Comment: Помимо практическх рекомендаций

Comment: тогда получается есть класс человек....потом мы вспомнили что человек еще может общаться, мы вводим новый абтрактный класс (в котором есть метод общение) , а данный базовый наследуем от него...(в данном случае и применяем данный принцип OPEN CLOSED и получаем единый класс) в котором человек может общаться..)

Comment: > Вы не знаете что будут делать с вашей к примеру библиотекой куда будут подключать ваши сущности и каким образом это будет происходить.   -   согласен, если библиотека вынесена в релиз, то естественно модификация публичных библиоте к(vendors) не допутсима....в этом случае естественно данный принцип соблюдается.....(речь шла именно о разработке до релиза)

Comment: Видимо данный прицнип подразумевается к релизной версии, а в разработке всеже допускается модификация кода уже существуюших классов.....Но опятьже хоть я и не имею права вносить изменения в компоненты сторонних разработчиков а только могу наследовать их классы.......всеже сам разработчик выпуская новую версию своего компонента имеет право модифицировать свои классы (т.е соблюдение Open Closed имеет место быть только между разными разработчиками), а автор имеет право менять свои класс (нарушая этот приницп) , даже авторы PHP в новых версиях переписывют свои классы бибилиотек.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, вопрос не решен, но в целом ситуация больше проясняется )), походу в википедии некорректный перевод данного прицнипа..

Comment: Конечно, речь не идёт о том, чтобы не менять класс вообще, потому что так все классы были бы с одним методом, потому что второй метод - это уже изменение класса :) Но при завершении этапа разработки (релиза версии, окончания подготовки pull request, ...) лучше привести код к такому состоянию, чтобы остальным в будущем не усложнять работу.